# DirectX 10 Drawing a .PNG

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, directx

I'm looking for a tutorial on how to draw a .PNG using DirectX 10, although I'm having no luck. Anyone know where I can find more information on this? I want to create a 2D game

Comment: When you want to create 2d games, I would recommend you to use a library like SDL or SFML. They take the burden of such low-level tasks for you so that you can concentrate on the interesting parts of game development. As another plus point, they work on multiple plattforms. That will make it a lot easier for you to create a Linux or Mac version of your game.

Answer (score 1):

You can load a png as a texture and render it the same way you render other images. For the transparency you can use Alphablending which you enable with Renderstates. ([Tutorial](http://www.rastertek.com/dx10tut11.html), only googled not tested)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `D3DX10CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile` to create a shader-resource view from a PNG file. [This](http://takinginitiative.net/2008/11/29/directx-10-tutorial-3-textures/) tutorial explains how it works.

In short:

- Create a shader to draw a rectangle
- Create vertex layout
- Create a vertex buffer which stores the vertices of the rectangle
- Create a sampler to sample the texture
- Create a texture object
- Draw the scene